# How to inject live-data from one Service in multiple components, angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I get live-data messages from a Client and want to show the data at the same time in 2 view-components. 
Mi idea is to use an abstract class or an interface.
This is my Client-Service, where i get the data from:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Paho} from '../../../../../node_modules/ng2-mqtt/mqttws31';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import {AddMqttformToClientService} from '../../add-live-data-button/forms/mqttform/add-mqttform-to-client.service';
import {AbstractClassService} from '../abstract-class.service';

@Injectable()
export class MqttProviderService extends AbstractClassService {

 // Create a client instance
  client: any;

  public constructor(private getformvaules: AddMqttformToClientService) {
   super();
    console.log("Generate Service");
    this.getformvaules.componentMethodCalled$.subscribe(
      () => {
        this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(this.getformvaules.addmqtt.addmqttadress, Number(this.getformvaules.addmqtt.addmqttport), this.getformvaules.addmqtt.addmqttusername);
        this.onConnectionLost();
        // connect the client
        this.client.connect({
          onSuccess: this.onConnected.bind(this)
        });
        //this.onDisconnect();
      }
    );
  }

  // called when the client connects
  onConnected() {
    let that = this;
    console.log('Connected');
    // this.client.subscribe('node/m1/temperature');
    // this.client.subscribe('node/m1/humidity');
    this.client.subscribe(this.getformvaules.addmqtt.addmqtttopicfilter);
    this.client.onMessageArrived = function(message) {
      that.onMessage(message.payloadString);
    };
  };


  // called when a message arrives
  public onMessage(msg: string) {
  }


  onDisconnect () {}

  // called when the client loses its connection
  onConnectionLost() {}

}
```

The abstract-class wih the onMessage method, which i want to inject in Component 1 and Component 2.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export abstract class AbstractClassService {

  public onMessage(msg: string): void {
  }
}
```

**Component 1:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractClassService} from '../../protocols/abstract-class.service';
import {MqttProviderService} from '../../protocols/mqtt/mqtt-provider.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-gauge',
      templateUrl: './gauge.component.html',
      providers: [{
        provide: AbstractClassService,
        useClass: MqttProviderService
      }
      ],
      styleUrls: ['./gauge.component.css']
    })
    export class GaugeComponent  {

      data = [
        {
          name: '',
          value: ''
        }
      ];


      constructor(private abstractclassService: AbstractClassService ) {
        this.abstractclassService.onMessage = (msg: string) => {
          this.data = [{name: 'test', value: msg}];

      };
}
```

**Component 2**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
    import {AbstractClassService} from '../../protocols/abstract-class.service';
    import {MqttProviderService} from '../../protocols/mqtt/mqtt-provider.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-gauge1',
      templateUrl: './gauge1.component.html',
      providers: [{
        provide: AbstractClassService,
        useClass: MqttProviderService
      }
      ],
      styleUrls: ['./gauge1.component.css']
    })
    export class GaugeComponent  {

      data = [
        {
          name: '',
          series: []
        },
      ];


      constructor(private abstractclassService: AbstractClassService ) {
        this.abstractclassService.onMessage = (msg: string) => {
               this.data1[0].series.push({ 'value': msg, 'name': String( new Date().getSeconds())});

      this.data = this.data.slice();

      };
}
```

At the moment i am getting just the data for **one** of the views! Depends on which component is named as second in the view-component:

```
<app-gauge></app-gauge> 
<app-gauge1></app-gauge1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are injecting in the components different instances of your service. This is because you are calling the service in both providers metadata field. You should use only one to allow your components to share the same data.
2. When I have to share live data this is what I do:

MyService:

```
@Injectable()
export class MqttProviderService {
  dataSubject: ReplaySubject<any>;
  data$: Observable<any>;

  constructor() {
   this.dataSubject = new ReplaySubject<any>();
   this.data$ = this.dataSubject.asObservable();
   methodToGetMyData();
  }

  methodToGetMyData() {
    //http call
    .subscribe((response: any) => this.dataSubject.next(response));
  }
}
```

With this configuration you can access your live data from the template doing this:

```
<span>myService.data$ | async</span>
```

And in your component/s you only need to inject the service in the constructor:

```
constructor(public myService: MqttProviderService) {}
```

One last thing, be sure you have your service in the providers field for the the module which contains your components.